Error from Keras: ValueError: Must provide at least one structure
I spotted weird problem with my script to train CNN model on Keras library. When I'm trying to learn simple CNN model during ending first epoch Keras throwing an error saying:

File "File.py", line 86, in 
generateModelForData(train_dataset, validation_dataset)
File "File.py", line 44, in generateModelForData
model.fit(train_dataset, batch_size=1, epochs=1000, verbose=1, validation_data=validation_dataset, callbacks=[my_callbacks])
File ".local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File ".local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/tree.py", line 236, in map_structure
raise ValueError("Must provide at least one structure")
ValueError: Must provide at least one structure

My model looks like that:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=[32, 128, 3]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(120, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_layer"))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
#
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)
#
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', Precision(), Recall(), AUC()])
my_callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=10, mode='max'), model_checkpoint_callback]
#
model.summary()
model.fit(train_dataset, batch_size=1, epochs=1000, verbose=1, validation_data=validation_dataset, callbacks=[my_callbacks])

Datasets is generated in that way:
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    batch_size=5,
    directory="new_heatmaps/train",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(32, 128),
    subset="training",
    class_mode="binary",
)

validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    batch_size=5,
    directory="new_heatmaps/test",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(32, 128),
    subset="validation",
    class_mode="binary",
)

What could be the cause of this structure error? When Keras throw some kind of error?

The issue you are facing , "typically occurs when you're passing an empty data structure or an invalid argument to a function in TensorFlow/Keras. In your case, it seems to be related to how you're passing the datasets to the fit()method.Your code snippets,I see that you're using the flow_from_directory method to generate your datasets. However,this method returns a DirectoryIterator object,not the actual dataset that can be passed directly to the fit() method You need to use the flow_from_directory method to generate batches of images and labels,and then pass those batches to the fit() method

No, that is not definitely a clue of this problem. This code works perfectly for different dataset. Also this error is thrown on the last iteration of my epoch, so definitely it is not a problem with flow_from_directory approach

This is a bit strange but I'll tell you what worked for me. And before posting this I verified a few times because with other datasets because the same as you -  this error was thrown only on some datasets, not others.

Open the folder with your training data (where you see all folders which are used as labels).
Sort them by date modified so the most recent on top
See how many images you have in the most recently modified folder. Make sure there are at least 8 images.


You do not need to specify the directory if you are using the "flow_from_directory" bit.

Finally after a lot of tests I found correct solution of this problem.
Previous two solutions didn't help: I had at least 8 images and not specifing directory didn't help.
Problem was with tagging subsets into training and validation. That prevents keras from loading correctly files to train and tests datasets.
Correct code for generating datasets should look like that:


train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    batch_size=5,
    directory="new_heatmaps/train",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(32, 128),
    class_mode="binary",
)

validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    batch_size=5,
    directory="new_heatmaps/test",
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(32, 128),
    class_mode="binary",
)



